# How to solve Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync C\:\\Users\\Name\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk/platform-tools/adb ENOENT in React native project?

Tags: android, react-native, adb

In my react-native project directory, whenever I run the following command to run the project-

> react-native run-android

The metro bundle starts and port 8081 is open but it shows the following error-

> Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync
>   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb
>   ENOENT

So, the app is not running in my adb device. I need a solution to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the path is using a mixture of backslashes and forward slashes:

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb

I would use that as the starting point for your investigation. Does RN know you are using Windows? Are you using a suitable CLI such as the one provided by Git SCM? I suspect you will have issues if you are running directly from cmd.